# I bought the vector .45acp in watch dogs but doesn't show up in my inventory. why and how do I get it?

Tags: watch-dogs

I bought the vector .45ACP in Watch Dogs but it does not show up in my inventory for weapons. Why and how do I get it to pop up on the wheel weapon inventory?

Comment: Could someone answer please. Itd be helpful.

Comment: not 100% sure, can check later, but don't you need a skill/ability unlock from one of the trees?

Comment: I just checked, there is one black vector but thats for online. Sadly, I do not have online. So I could not get that achievement unlocked as well as the gun itself. So I just would like to know how to get the vector from the gun stores. Money isn't a concern so whatever the cost is, I'm good.

Comment: Anyone think they can help

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but do you know how to cycle between weapons? You might have the gun unlocked, but you don't know how to change to it.

Comment: Well since my system is a ps3, I would hold down the L1 button, use the right analog stick to pick which type of weapon, then use the the directional pad to change. I looked through all of them and have not seen the vector

Comment: I can change the gun I want in the gun wheel selection but its not there. I've looked in the four slots available and it never show's itself.

Comment: I just recently got the black suppressed vector but its not the one I want (sorry for being stubborn) so my question still goes, how do I get it to be on my weapon wheel.